# operator expected after expression

Tags: prolog

I have those facts

```
   relationship(nikos,anna,husband).
    type_of_service(nikos,hospital).
    insurance_cover(nikos,partial).
    type_of_insurance(nikos,family).
    refund_request(nikos,5000).
```

I wrote the below

```
refund(Insured , insuranceCover, hospital, requestedRefund, Poso):-
hospital_refund(Insured, insuranceCover, requestedRefund, Poso).

hospital_refund(Insured, partial, requestedRefund, Poso):-
requestedRefund <= 5000,Poso = requestedRefund. %% <--- Error

hospital_refund(Insured, full, requestedRefund, Poso):-
Poso = requestedRefund.

apozemiose(Insured, Poso):-
refund(Insured, insurance_cover(Insured ,X),
    type_of_service(Insured),
    refund_request(Insured , X)
).
```

If a person has a hospital insurance it takes a refund and the amount depends on the type of the insurance, if its partial or a full one.

What I want is to be able to ask how much refund a person can have.
Specifically `?- apozemiose (nikos, Poso).`

I get an error *operator expected after expression* , I'm sure there is some kind of syntax error where is the comparison.

Comment: Did you check the Prolog manual for acceptable inequality predicates? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

syntax error apart, you'll need to change also the last clause

```
apozemiose(Insured, Poso):-
  insurance_cover(Insured, I),
  type_of_service(Insured, T),
  refund_request(Insured, R),
  refund(Insured, I,T,R, Poso).
```

*edit* here is a set of corrections, mainly introducing **variables** where you used **atoms**, i.e. literal constants

```
refund(Insured, InsuranceCover, hospital, RequestedRefund, Poso):-
    hospital_refund(Insured, InsuranceCover, RequestedRefund, Poso).

hospital_refund(_Insured, partial, RequestedRefund, Poso):-
    RequestedRefund =< 5000, Poso = RequestedRefund.
hospital_refund(_Insured, full, RequestedRefund, Poso):-
    Poso = RequestedRefund.
```

as a stylistic choice, I would avoid assignments in rules body, that is:

```
hospital_refund(_Insured, partial, RequestedRefund, RequestedRefund):-
    RequestedRefund =< 5000.
hospital_refund(_Insured, full, RequestedRefund, RequestedRefund).
```

but that of course depends on having rules so simple like these...

*full code* after comment:

```
relationship(nikos,anna,husband).
type_of_service(nikos,hospital).
insurance_cover(nikos,partial).
type_of_insurance(nikos,family).
refund_request(nikos,5000).

refund(Insured, InsuranceCover, hospital, RequestedRefund, Poso):-
    hospital_refund(Insured, InsuranceCover, RequestedRefund, Poso).

hospital_refund(_Insured, partial, RequestedRefund, Poso):-
    RequestedRefund =< 5000, Poso = RequestedRefund.
hospital_refund(_Insured, full, RequestedRefund, Poso):-
    Poso = RequestedRefund.

apozemiose(Insured, Poso):-
    insurance_cover(Insured, I),
    type_of_service(Insured, T),
    refund_request(Insured, R),
    refund(Insured, I,T,R, Poso).
```

test:

```
?- apozemiose(nikos, Poso).
Poso = 5000 ;
false.
```

HTH

Comment: Thx for the correction. But why I get `no` as an answer where I ask `apozemiose(nikos, Poso)`? Shouldn't it be `5000`?

Comment: Ok stupid question, do I have to make capital the first letter for variables?

Answer (score 3):

You don't use `<=` in Prolog. The right syntax is `=<`.